# Can i customize the code that is auto-generated for properties in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have dug myself a hole by changing the order of interface implementation for some classes. As it stands right now, I need to go through and expand alot of properties to implement a Get and Set. The Get and Set methods are very similar, but tricky enough to make it hard to automate. Example:

```
Public Property SpecificTable as SpecificTableType
```

I have properties similar to this, which i need to expand to something like:

```
Public Property SpecificTable as SpecificTableType
Get
  Return DirectCast(Me.Table, SpecificTableType)
End Get
Set(ByVal value as SpecificTableType)
  Me.Table = value
End Set
```

Its pretty simple, and VS Studio will auto generate alot of it when i just type Get and hit enter under the property, including the `Set(ByVal value as SpecificTableType)`

Which made me wonder, snippets aside, because i already have the properties defined, how does VS accomplish this auto generation, and can i customize it? it would save my fingers some pain.

Comment: remove all props, generate all props again? very easy. would this work?

Comment: I dont think so unforunately. I have 300+ files with similar properties, but different types. At this point, i am going through each, and typing Get, hitting enter, then filling in the get and set manually.

Comment: I wonder if some clever macros would be useful for you?

Comment: This code is just text in text files. You're a programmer! Write a program to read the files, find these lines, identify the property name & the type, and generate the code snippets for you and resave the files. Doesn't need to be a macro.

Comment: I had considered this, however the real scenario isnt as peachy as i first described, there is significant variation within some of the files. Some of them are old enough to have explicitly defined properties, with member level variables, some of them have sideskirted implementing the interface by simply implementing the properties locally, and ignoring the constraints. Yay. The gotchas involved in the parsing might negate much of the benefit.

Comment: I wish they would just let me use the intern..

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio does not by default allow you to customize that aspect of code generation, beyond allowing you to disable the automatic insertion of 'End construct' lines (End If, End Get, etc).

There are some extensions that allow template driven code generation like: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4fbfd05a-f3e8-4f79-b912-def3e9cb28fc?SRC=VSIDE

see if that fits your bill.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case. I had hoped with their snippet/macro support that maybe i could customize it. Oh well. I am checking out the CodeSmith extension. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely interesting, but in the end, i dont think it gives me much more than snippets. The problem with my situation is that i need to constrain a type based upon the property already written in the code. Essentially what VS does when it auto creates the Set(ByVal value as <TYPE>). Thanks for your answer, it appears i will need to get out the stress ball.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difficult way to do it, but definitely an answer if you want to take the time to learn Roslyn and write a code issue.

Use Microsoft Roslyn, a compiler as a service project that allows you to get access to the parser, compiler (semantic) functionality. What you can do with Roslyn is create an abstract syntax tree based on an a file (loop over the files of all types) and for each AST search for properties that don't contain getter and setter explicitly defined and replace that AST with one that has the props the way you like them.

This is what I would do if I need to redo this where simple replacement applications wouldn't do.

Check these out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx